# How to shorten boolean function

Tags: c#, function, boolean

I have to **shorten** boolean function to *one line*. I'm a begginer in C# and I have no idea, how to shorten it.

```
    static bool mod(int number) 
    {
        if (number % 3 == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want this:

```
static bool mod(int number){    
   return number % 3 == 0;
}
```

Comment: pfft that's not one line. We need full codegolf! `static bool mod(int n){return n%3==0;}` ;)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre: :-D :-D :-D

Comment: Hum. I've converged on this answer with some help from comments. Upvoted as you're clearly the expert.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre `static bool mod(int n) => n%3==0;` will do

Answer (score 6):

I'm the winner? [Expression bodied functions are new in C#6](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

```
static bool Mod(int number) => number % 3 == 0;
```

Comment: This is the best answer to achieve what OP is actually asking.

Comment: @Botonomous **IF** you're using C#6

Comment: This approaches the elegance of a language invented in the 1970s. Have an upvote.

Comment: Very true, Although I think its fair to assume c# 6 if none is specified. Considering it's 2 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Just return the expression inside the `if`-statement:

```
static bool mod(int number) 
{
    return number % 3 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simply `number % 3 == 0`, either inline, or as the function body. If you do retain it as a function then do consider renaming the function to `mod_by_3` or similar.

In C and C++ you can ace it with the considerably clearer `!(number % 3)`.

Comment: Errr... this looks like C... this won't compile in C# or am I missing something?

Comment: @RenéVogt: Oops, C# version added: in some ways it's more elegant but is a touchstone for your knowledge of operator precedence: Quiche eaters might want to see `(number % 3) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
static bool mod(int number) 
{
    return number % 3 == 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sethu Bala; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.